# How To Calculate Month From The Total Number Of Days Difference In Hebrew Calendar

Tags: java, calendar, hebrew

I am using [this](https://www.easycalculation.com/date-day/hebrew-calendar-date-difference.php) to calculate the number of days difference in hebrew calendar and it returns correct days difference. Now I want to convert those days in the months or years.

But the problem is in the Hebrew calendar

> A year in the Hebrew calendar can be 353, 354, 355, 383, 384, or 385
>   days long. Regular common years have 12 months with a total of 354
>   days. Leap years have 13 months and are 384 days long. Months with
>   uneven numbers usually have 30 days, while months with even numbers
>   have 29 days.

I have tried to divide the days with total days in a year but it has a different total number of days in the year.  Can you please me an idea of how to achieve this?

Comment: totally off topic, but some years with 12 months, others with 13? oh yahveh...

Comment: So how would you get month difference from total days in hebrew calendar

Comment: it's clear you need all the data from...the beginning of the hebrew calendar?

Comment: Interesting question... I had a look at [`ChronoLocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDate.html) and was expecting something like `HebrewDate`, but there isn't anything like that!

Comment: Could you give examples of inputs and expected outputs? I don't quite understand *exactly* what you're looking for at the moment, and calendrical calculations are hard enough even when the requirements *are* precise.

Comment: [This](http://www.david-greve.de/luach-code/jewish-java.html) is quite old, but may provide some useful methods or ideas.

Comment: I am using this link https://www.easycalculation.com/date-day/hebrew-calendar-date-difference.php for getting the total number of days between two hebrew date and I want to calculate the months from that total days.

Comment: I wouldn't reinvent the wheel. Look at [com.ibm.icu.util.HebrewCalendar](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/HebrewCalendar.html). Or if you only want to implement small modifications yourself this link might help you [Jewish calendar calculation in Java](http://www.david-greve.de/luach-code/jewish-java.html)

Comment: Thanks for providing these links and going through it

Comment: @aran Moon calendar, I guess. That doesn't line up with solar year so there are leap years with 13 months to align it back so the seasons don't shift too much?

Comment: @kutschkem interesting, thanks for that info!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a loop that keeps subtracting is the easiest to be understood. I guess you know the year at either end of the difference. Then a loop like this could work:

```
int yearBegin = 1234;
int daysDiff = calcDaysDiff(); // your existing routine
int yearAnalyzing = yearBegin;
int years = 0;
while (daysDiff > 0) {
    int daysInThatYear = calcDaysInYear (yearAnalyzing); // you calc accdg your rules
    while (daysDiff >= daysInThatYear) {
        ++years;
        daysDiff -= daysinThatYear;
        yearAnalyzing++; // or --, depending which direction you want to go
    }
    // less than a year is left
    // calculate the months (should be easy)
}
```

If your beginning date starts in the middle of the year you would have to work these days off your difference first, before you start the loop.

Comment: Thanks let me try this way then I'll let you know

Comment: You cannot convert a day-difference into a month diff without knowing the start or end date because the day difference might stretch a leap month or not, see also my answer.

Comment: @MenoHochschild , You are right, I am getting a issue in leap year while calculating month and year for total day difference betweeen two hebrew dates

Answer (score 0):

You can use my lib [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) which offers the feature to determine differences measured in years, months or days. Example (from a JUnit test case):

```
    HebrewCalendar start = HebrewCalendar.of(5778, HebrewMonth.HESHVAN, 6);
    HebrewCalendar end = HebrewCalendar.of(5778, HebrewMonth.ELUL, 6);

    assertThat(HebrewCalendar.Unit.MONTHS.between(start, end), is(10));

    start = start.plus(CalendarDays.ONE);
    assertThat(HebrewCalendar.Unit.MONTHS.between(start, end), is(9));

    start = start.minus(3, HebrewCalendar.Unit.YEARS);
    assertThat(HebrewCalendar.Unit.YEARS.between(start, end), is(3));

    start = start.plus(6, HebrewCalendar.Unit.YEARS).minus(CalendarDays.of(2)); // AM-5781-HESHVAN-5
    assertThat(HebrewCalendar.Unit.YEARS.between(start, end), is(-2));

    start = start.with(HebrewCalendar.MONTH_OF_YEAR, HebrewMonth.ELUL); // AM-5781-ELUL-5
    assertThat(HebrewCalendar.Unit.MONTHS.between(start, end), is(-36));

    start = start.plus(CalendarDays.ONE);
    assertThat(HebrewCalendar.Unit.MONTHS.between(start, end), is(-37));

    start = start.minus(37, HebrewCalendar.Unit.MONTHS);
    assertThat(start, is(end));
```

The logic is somehow similar to the standard logic in the `java.time`-package. When the day-of-month of end date is smaller than that of start date, then the calculated month delta (or year delta) will be decreased by one.

Generally I cannot recommend to try to convert days into months or years applying a fixed factor because the Hebrew calendar has sometimes 12, sometimes 13 months. My lib does not try it, too, but applies an optimized kind of counting. **It is also impossible to convert a day delta to a month delta without any further informations about start or end date for principal reasons:**

```
Imagine the SAME day delta had been determined with a start date 
short before Adar I (leap month) or with another month later. Then the month
delta will be different because the second case does not include a leap month!
```

More examples how to handle the Hebrew calendar can be seen in the [API online](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/HebrewCalendar.html).

If you are on Android then please use the specialized derivate [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A) with similar API.

Comment: Thanks, I will go through this and will let you know